# Biztalk BRE not evaluating condition correctly

Tags: biztalk, business-rules

I am implementing a simple BRE example from Biztalk Certification Guide. My policy is composed as follows:

[image]

Seems easy. But then I am trying to test my policy with XML that has LoanAmount = 20. And BRE tells me, that 20<100 = false:

```
Test Expression: TypedXmlDocument:LoanApp:/LoanApp.LoanAmount < 100
Left Operand Value: 20
Right Operand Value: 100
Test Result: False
```

When I am testing policy with the same XML that has LoantAmount = 10 everything works fine:

```
Test Expression: TypedXmlDocument:LoanApp:/LoanApp.LoanAmount < 100
Left Operand Value: 10
Right Operand Value: 100
Test Result: True
```

Seems to be some awkward magic.

Answer (score 1):

Just recognized that it is compared as string, because `LoanAmount` schema element is a string type.